# Change img to background image in PHP loop jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, image, loops

I'm trying to convert loaded `img`tags to background images using jQuery, however, the images are being loaded in a PHP while loop. When I try implementing the jQuery, only the last `img` tag is looked at by the jQuery. Here is my code

**PHP**

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbleads, "SELECT * FROM plugin_blog WHERE published = 1 ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,20");
$i = 0;
$j=-1;
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    preg_match('/(<img[^>]+>)/i', $row['html'], $matches);
    $img = $matches[1];
    ++$i;
    if ($i%2 == 0){
        ++$j;
        echo "<div class='masonryImage tweets' style='width:300px; height:175px;'><div class='tweet-content'>" . $tweets[$j] . "</div></div>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<div class='masonryImage blogImage' style='width: 300px; height:200px;'>" . $img . " </div>";
    }
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$j('div.blogImage img').each(function() { 
   var imageSrc = $j(this).attr('src');

   $j(this).remove();
   $j('.blogImage').html('<div class="backbg"></div>');
   $j('.backbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
   $j('.backbg').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
   $j('.backbg').css('background-position','center');
   $j('.backbg').css('background-size','cover');
   $j('.backbg').css('width','100%');
   $j('.backbg').css('height','100%');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's $j in javascript?  If you're trying to use the jQuery object, it's either "jQuery" or "$".  Have you checked your javascript console?  I suspect the $j is causing errors.

Comment: Hi there, I am loading another Javascript library, so $j is replacing $/jQuery via noConflict :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting every .backbg's css on the last iteration.
When you run `$j('.backbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');` the last time, you are saying "find EVERY .backbg, even the ones I've already done, and set their css".

You need to do something like:

```
var imageSrc = $j(this).attr('src');
var blogImg = $j(this).parent();
$j(this).remove();
blogImg.html('<div class="backbg"></div>');
blogImg.find('.backbg').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
```

Comment: Worked a treat, just added the css for .backbg in the CSS file. Thanks a lot :)